# Use Nagios hostgroups in check_cluster --service check?

Tags: nagios, icinga

Is there a way to use hostgroups within a `check_cluster --service` check?

I've only seen examples that list out each host in the cluster individually like this:

```
define service{
    ...

    check_command   check_service_cluster!"Foo Cluster"!0!1!$SERVICESTATEID:host1:DNS Service$,$SERVICESTATEID:host2:DNS Service$,$SERVICESTATEID:host3:DNS Service$
    ...

}
```

But this seems very unwieldy for large clusters. Is there a way to pass it a whole hostgroup directly, `$SERVICESTATEID:dns_hostgroup`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use hostgroups or servicegroups with this plugin, unfortunately.

However: new versions of the plugins support using an extra config ("ini") file. So you could write a script to take a host/servicegroup, look up everything in it, and generate a conf file from that.

Or, you might want to look at [check_multi](http://my-plugin.de/wiki/projects/check_multi/start) instead. It's much better at this sort of thing, and it's easy to generate its conf via a script.

Comment: last release 2011/11